PyTorch Lightning Distributed Training Timeout error with NCCL Backend
I'm using Pytorch Lightning to run a distributed training Python script using the DDP. I'm using a DDPStrategy to define the backend, a custom timeout and a custom cluster environment as a ClusterEnvironment class implementation
My training code part looks like
    strategy = DDPStrategy(
            cluster_environment=CustomEnvironment(),
            process_group_backend="nccl",
            timeout=CUSTOM_TIMEOUT,
            find_unused_parameters=True)

    # Initialize a trainer
    trainer = pl.Trainer(logger=logger,
                        callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
                         max_epochs=hparams["epochs"],
                         devices=devices,
                         accelerator=accelerator,
                         strategy=strategy)

where devices = 4 (because I have 4 gpus per node), accelerator = "gpu" and the class CustomEnvironment is defined as follows
from typing import Union,Any,Dict
from pytorch_lightning.plugins.environments import ClusterEnvironment
from pytorch_lightning.strategies.ddp import DDPStrategy
from datetime import timedelta
DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = timedelta(seconds=1800)
CUSTOM_TIMEOUT = timedelta(seconds=3600)

class CustomEnvironment(ClusterEnvironment):
    def __init__(self, num_nodes=2):
        super().__init__()
        self._num_nodes = num_nodes
        self._master_port = None
        self._world_size = None
        self._global_rank = None

    def creates_processes_externally(self):
        # Assuming PyTorch Lightning manages processes internally
        return False

    def detect(self):
        # Implement detection of nodes and processes if necessary
        log.debug("Detect method is called.")

    def global_rank(self):
        if self._global_rank is None:
            self._global_rank = int(os.getenv("RANK", 0))
        log.debug(f"GLOBAL_RANK: {self._global_rank}")
        return self._global_rank

    @property
    def main_address(self):
        return self.master_address()

    @property
    def main_port(self):
        return self.master_port()

    def set_global_rank(self, rank: int):
        self._global_rank = rank
        log.debug(f"Set GLOBAL_RANK: {self._global_rank}")

    def set_world_size(self, world_size: int):
        self._world_size = world_size
        log.debug(f"Set WORLD_SIZE: {self._world_size}")

    def master_address(self):
        MASTER_ADDR = os.getenv("MASTER_ADDR")
        log.debug(f"MASTER_ADDR: {MASTER_ADDR}")
        return MASTER_ADDR

    def master_port(self):
        if self._master_port is None:
            self._master_port = os.getenv("MASTER_PORT")
        log.debug(f"MASTER_PORT: {self._master_port}")
        return int(self._master_port)

    def world_size(self):
        if self._world_size is None:
            log.debug("WORLD_SIZE is not set.")
        return self._world_size

    def node_rank(self):
        MY_RANK = int(os.getenv("NODE_RANK", "0"))
        log.debug(f"NODE_RANK: {MY_RANK}")
        return int(MY_RANK)

    def local_rank(self) -> int:
        LOCAL_RANK = int(os.getenv("LOCAL_RANK", "0"))
        log.debug(f"LOCAL_RANK: {LOCAL_RANK}")
        return LOCAL_RANK

On the master I get this configuration
DEBUG:train:NODE_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:LOCAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:Set GLOBAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:Set WORLD_SIZE: 8
DEBUG:train:GLOBAL_RANK: 0
GPU available: True (cuda), used: True
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
2024-08-21 17:51:24 training on gpu with 4 gpu
DEBUG:train:LOCAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:LOCAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:NODE_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:NODE_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:LOCAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:Set GLOBAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:Set WORLD_SIZE: 8
DEBUG:train:GLOBAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:GLOBAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:GLOBAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:MASTER_ADDR: 10.0.147.2
DEBUG:train:MASTER_PORT: 9001
Initializing distributed: GLOBAL_RANK: 0, MEMBER: 1/8

while on the client I get
DEBUG:train:NODE_RANK: 1
DEBUG:train:LOCAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:Set GLOBAL_RANK: 4
DEBUG:train:Set WORLD_SIZE: 8
DEBUG:train:GLOBAL_RANK: 4
2024-08-21 17:51:24 training on gpu with 4 gpu
DEBUG:train:LOCAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:LOCAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:NODE_RANK: 1
DEBUG:train:NODE_RANK: 1
DEBUG:train:LOCAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:Set GLOBAL_RANK: 4
DEBUG:train:Set WORLD_SIZE: 8
DEBUG:train:GLOBAL_RANK: 4
DEBUG:train:GLOBAL_RANK: 4
DEBUG:train:GLOBAL_RANK: 4
DEBUG:train:MASTER_ADDR: 10.0.147.2
DEBUG:train:MASTER_PORT: 9001
Initializing distributed: GLOBAL_RANK: 4, MEMBER: 5/8
DEBUG:train:LOCAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:LOCAL_RANK: 0
DEBUG:train:GLOBAL_RANK: 4

that are coherent with the env I setup for the MASTER_ADDR, MASTER_PORT, NODE_RANK and WORLD_SIZE required minimal env, where in my configuration I have
4 GPUS x 2 nodes hence WORLD_SIZE is set to 8.
Additionally I have manually setup NCCL envs for the network interfaces I have from ipconfig on the host and to disable P2P if any (The NCCL_P2P_DISABLE variable disables the peer to peer (P2P) transport, which uses CUDA direct access between GPUs, using NVLink or PCI).
export NCCL_SOCKET_IFNAME=eth0
export NCCL_P2P_DISABLE=1

I have a timeout error with this configuration, despite of the time set. Specifically on the MASTER I get a TCPStore error
    return TCPStore(
torch.distributed.DistStoreError: Timed out after 1801 seconds waiting for clients. 2/4 clients joined.

and then on the CLIENT I get the disconnect error
[rank4]:[W821 14:18:47.728693991 socket.cpp:428] [c10d] While waitForInput, poolFD failed with (errno: 0 - Success).
2024-08-21 14:18:47 [4] is setting up NCCL communicator and retrieving ncclUniqueId from [0] via c10d key-value store by key '0', but store->get('0') got error: Connection reset by peer
...
torch.distributed.DistBackendError: [4] is setting up NCCL communicator and retrieving ncclUniqueId from [0] via c10d key-value store by key '0', but store->get('0') got error: Connection reset by peer

